# mui cannot override size style to Rating component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I cannot override default style of MUI Rating component. No matter what it defaults to medium 24 fontSize, and does not increase it. What had I done wrong?

```
import { Rating } from '@mui/material';

export const Stars = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Rating name="size-large" defaultValue={2} size="large" />
      <Rating
        name="size-large"
        value={4.5}
        precision={0.5}
        sx={{ fontSize: '48px' }}
        size="large"
        readOnly
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.115",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.9",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.22.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
```

[image]

Comment: I applied css property scale - to solve this issue. The initial problem might be with package.json file - no idea what exactly causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not calling this component and seeing some other component. Your code has the first stars with a default value of 2, but your screenshot shows the value at 440 / 550.

Or you may have an MUI Ratings *style override* or *global stylesheet* preventing the inline `sx` styling from taking hold.

You can right click `Inspect` the stars you are expecting to have a `font-size: 48px` then see what CSS stylesheet it's getting it's actual font-size from.

Using your code and dependencies in a [simple sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-ratings-fontsize-cy2cxx) I see the larger stars as expected.

Comment: For some reason * {}  globally applied css styles from index.css are overriding any styles that are passed in  sx={SRatingSX} or styled={{}} props. Solution might be to lift import css up in index.ts file, but that is not ideal. So I just opted with scale property here.